# Problem using greenlet to execute multiple functions simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, coroutine

The following script has the purpose of execute many functions simultaneously, but i don't have idea why it's not working correctly.
The functions are executed in sequential way, not parallel.

I would appreciate any suggestion to clarify me, about what i'm doing wrong.

```
import time
import eventlet


EXECUTION_TIMEOUT = 10

def example(name, steps_limit):
    print 'Starting process %s with %d steps' % (name, steps_limit)
    for i in range(1, steps_limit+1):
        print "Process %s, step %d" % (name, i)
        time.sleep(2)
    print 'Finishing process %s with %d steps' % (name, steps_limit)


def fetch(input_data):
    example(input_data['name'], input_data['steps'])

test_data = [{'name':'proceso1', 'steps':3},
             {'name':'proceso2', 'steps':5},
             {'name':'proceso3', 'steps':6},
             ]

def main():
    #Setting up time out
    timeout = eventlet.timeout.Timeout(EXECUTION_TIMEOUT)
    #initialize pool
    pool = eventlet.GreenPool(size=1000)
    try:
        for hits in pool.imap(fetch, test_data):
            pass
    except eventlet.Timeout:
        print 'Operation interrupted by timeout concept'
    finally:
        timeout.cancel()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please include any error messages you're getting, and be more specific as to what's happening. does it return immediately? Does it hang forever? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: There is not error messages, it does not hang forever. The problem is that the process happens in a sequantial way, not unordered. Each function start, when the previous finished. i don't wish that.

Comment: I already see what is my error. I´m using "time.sleep" instead of "eventlet.sleep". The difference is that the last does not block the whole interpreter and thus lets the other greenlets to proceed with their requests as well. Thanks to myself for this time ;-).... and i hope that this dummy question helps to others....

Answer (score 2):

You're right about `time.sleep()` being the culprit.

But you don't have to replace `time.sleep()` with `eventlet.sleep()`. Instead, you can monkey patch `time.sleep` to become `eventlet.sleep`.

This is, in fact, preferred, because that way the libraries that you did not know use `time.sleep` also get fixed whereas if you fix it yourself you only fixed your code.

For this reason, in [gevent](http://gevent.org/), we just recommend to call `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` for all programs. In eventlet, there's a similar function exists.

Comment: thanks for your valuable clarification. With evenlet, you get the same effect using. 
eventlet.monkey_patch()

Even, you can specify which module you want monkey patch. For example, for only monkey patch time module, 
eventlet.monkey_patch(time=True)